# How do i capture mfcc and spectral_contrast from audio using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a set of audios as dataset in .wav format, how can i extract features from the audios and classify them into different categories using python and tensorflow. I am open to other python libraries also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking forward for classification of audios, [this](https://aqibsaeed.github.io/2016-09-03-urban-sound-classification-part-1/) is a great start.

Requires:

1. tensorflow
2. librosa
3. matplotlib
4. numpy

Comment: edited your question for other users to understand the requirement exactly